# SQLite - Find out if some customer was referred by already existing customer

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, self-join

I need to find out if some customer was referred by already existing customer.
Return results in following format "Customer Last name Customer First name" "Last name First name of customer who recomended the new customer"

Here are my sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id int,
    last_name varchar(50),
    first_name varchar(50),
    referred_by_id varchar(50));
    
INSERT INTO customers (customer_id,last_name,first_name, referred_by_id)
    VALUES (1,'John','White',''),
        (2,'Sarah','Green',''),
        (3,'George','Black',''),
        (4,'Mark','Koon',''),
        (5,'Tom','Gone',''),
        (6,'Ezra','Beck',''),
        (7,'Jan','Wick',2),
        (8,'Petr','Lame',''),
        (9,'Lucy','Can',''),
        (10,'Karl','Opel',1),
        (11,'Ron','Varon',10),
        (12,'Harry','Bond',''),
        (13,'Paul','Kong',''),
        (14,'Shaun','King',3),
        (15,'Elisabeth','Yellow','');
        
CREATE TABLE contacts (
    customer_id int,
    address varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    phone_number varchar(20),
    email VARCHAR(255));
    
    
INSERT INTO contacts (customer_id,address,city,phone_number,email)
    VALUES (1,'3525  Fort Street','COLUMBUS','2532326578','JW@email.com'),
        (2,'3924  Cooks Mine Road','Albuquerque','5057657670','SarahG@email.com'),
        (3,'925  College Street','Atlanta','4043278560','Georgie@email.com');

CREATE TABLE orders (
    customer_id int,
    order_id INT,
    item varchar(50),
    order_value DECIMAL(12,2),
    order_currency varchar(3),
    order_date TIMESTAMP);
 
INSERT INTO orders (customer_id,order_id,item,order_value,order_currency,order_date)
    VALUES(1,1,'HDMI cable',3.25,'EUR','2020-01-21 14:50:04'),
        (2,2,'Keyboard','15.99','EUR','2020-01-21 17:50:04'),
        (3,3,'Charger','9.99','EUR','2020-01-22 18:00:07'),
        (3,3,'Charger','9.99','EUR','2020-01-22 18:00:07'),
        (3,4,'Phone','225.89','EUR','2020-01-22 19:10:56'),
        (2,5,'Camera','199.99','EUR','2020-01-23 07:50:44'),
        (1,6,'Speakers','75.50','EUR','2020-01-23 08:40:00'),
        (1,6,'Speakers','75.50','EUR','2020-01-23 08:40:00'),
        (2,7,'Mouse','22.19','EUR','2020-01-23 09:20:59');
```

Comment: What have you tried?  How do you define "existing" customer?

Comment: So you see some customers have reffered_by_id value. This reffered_by_id is the id of customer who reffered new customer. Now I need to get result : name of "new" customer and name of customer who reffered him/her.

Comment: @Adamooo I think that in your sample data you posted the last names should be first names and vice versa.

Comment: Yes you are right, there is a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self join of the table `customers`:

```
SELECT c1.last_name || ' ' || c1.first_name customer_name,
       c2.last_name || ' ' || c2.first_name referred_by
FROM customers c1 INNER JOIN customers c2
ON c2.customer_id = c1.referred_by_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6830341c54813071898e621bee302dea).
Results (for the sample data that you posted):

```
> customer_name | referred_by 
> :------------ | :-----------
> Jan Wick      | Sarah Green 
> Karl Opel     | John White  
> Ron Varon     | Karl Opel   
> Shaun King    | George Black
```